# Простая анимация svg

Tags: svg, анимация, css-animation, svg-animation

Нужно реализовать циклическое изменение цвета svg элемента в течении к примеру 5 секунд, но цвет должен меняться сверху в низ(это и не получается). Как это сделать через css?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот такой результат хочу получить, сама стрелка это svg. Не выходит такая анимация цвета заливки

```html
<svg class="main-arrow main-arrow_bottom">
               <path d="M8.5 34.6804C8.5 34.9565 8.72386 35.1804 9 35.1804C9.27614 35.1804 9.5 34.9565 9.5 34.6804H8.5ZM9 0L9.38168 -0.32299C9.28668 -0.435254 9.14707 -0.5 9 -0.5C8.85293 -0.5 8.71332 -0.435254 8.61832 -0.32299L9 0ZM17.6183 10.9583C17.7967 11.1691 18.1122 11.1954 18.323 11.017C18.5338 10.8386 18.5601 10.5231 18.3817 10.3123L17.6183 10.9583ZM-0.381677 10.3123C-0.56006 10.5231 -0.533784 10.8386 -0.32299 11.017C-0.112195 11.1954 0.203295 11.1691 0.381677 10.9583L-0.381677 10.3123ZM9.5 34.6804V0H8.5V34.6804H9.5ZM8.61832 0.32299L17.6183 10.9583L18.3817 10.3123L9.38168 -0.32299L8.61832 0.32299ZM0.381677 10.9583L9.38168 0.32299L8.61832 -0.32299L-0.381677 10.3123L0.381677 10.9583Z" transform="translate(1 1.04108)"/>
               </svg>
```

Comment: сейчас отредактирую вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавляем `<animate .../>` к `stop` `linearGradient`'a, в качестве атрибута используем `offset`, которому меняем значение от 0 до 1:

```css
body {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 150 150'>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id='linear-gradient' x1='50%' y1='100%' x2='50%' y2='0%'>
      <stop offset="0" stop-color='red'>
      <!--HERE-->
        <animate attributeName='offset' values='0;1;0' dur='6s' fill='freeze' repeatCount='indefinite'/> 
      </stop>
      <stop offset='0' stop-color='white'/>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <path d='M8.5 34.6804C8.5 34.9565 8.72386 35.1804 9 35.1804C9.27614 35.1804 9.5 34.9565 9.5 34.6804H8.5ZM9 0L9.38168 -0.32299C9.28668 -0.435254 9.14707 -0.5 9 -0.5C8.85293 -0.5 8.71332 -0.435254 8.61832 -0.32299L9 0ZM17.6183 10.9583C17.7967 11.1691 18.1122 11.1954 18.323 11.017C18.5338 10.8386 18.5601 10.5231 18.3817 10.3123L17.6183 10.9583ZM-0.381677 10.3123C-0.56006 10.5231 -0.533784 10.8386 -0.32299 11.017C-0.112195 11.1954 0.203295 11.1691 0.381677 10.9583L-0.381677 10.3123ZM9.5 34.6804V0H8.5V34.6804H9.5ZM8.61832 0.32299L17.6183 10.9583L18.3817 10.3123L9.38168 -0.32299L8.61832 0.32299ZM0.381677 10.9583L9.38168 0.32299L8.61832 -0.32299L-0.381677 10.3123L0.381677 10.9583Z' transform='translate(1 1.04108)' stroke='url(#linear-gradient)'/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!

Comment: @АртурСимонян, всегда пожалуйста=)